# End tag a violates nesting rules. Why is that?

Tags: html

I'm double checking my code right now for an assignment. When I go to check, it says that it is violating nesting rules, but this is the only way I am able to get this bordered "view menu" button to link to a specific page I need. What is there wrong here?

The code is:

```
<div class="indexbody"></div>
<div class="img1"></div> <!--lantern.html image class-->
    <a class="viewmenu" href="menu.html"> <!--Linking border text with href-->
    <div  class="menutext">
    <span class="border ">
    View Our Menu
    </span>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Rule: every tag you open has to be closed before you close a parent tag. You opened a `<div>` as a child of `<a>`, but then tried to close `</a>` before closing `</div>`. You might try formattng your code to make it easier to see the problem. `<a>` should not be indented here because it's a sibling of the `<div>`s above it.

Comment: You'll have an easier time of things if you use consistent indentation (most IDEs should handle that for you).

Answer (score 1):

Your closing `</div>` tag is in the wrong order. Try this:

```
<div class="indexbody"></div>
<div class="img1"></div> <!--lantern.html image class-->
<a class="viewmenu" href="menu.html"> <!--Linking border text with href-->
    <div  class="menutext">
    <span class="border ">
    View Our Menu
    </span>
    </div> <!--Out-of-order tag-->
</a>
```